# Equality of corresponding variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question might be silly, but I was wondering for $x_1 y_1 + y_1 = x_2 y_2 + y_2$ , $y_1 = y_2$ is true. And likewise, $x_1 y_1 = x_2 y_2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking whether

$$x_1 y_1 + y_1 = x_2 y_2 + y_2$$

implies that $y_1 = y_2$. Note that we can factor the two sides as

$$y_1 (x_1 + 1) = y_2 (x_2 + 1)$$

Hence the answer is *no*: Take $y_1 = 2$, $x_1 = 4$ along with $y_2 = 1$ and $x_2 = 9$ for a counterexample.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant to ask. And is this relation: $_a_x_ +_b_ = _c_x_ + _d_$ implies $_a_ = _c_$ related to it somehow?

Comment: @o.johann The second relation is about polynomials: It's a general faction that two polynomials are equal if and only if all the coefficients are the same.

Comment: All clear. Thanks